# How do you manually trigger an event?

Tags: autocmd, events

I have case where I would like to trigger the `TextChanged` event manually without actually changing the text. Would that be possible? How?

I know it's hacky, but it would make my life easier right now. :)

Comment: Are you aware of `:doautocmd`?

Comment: No. Do I understand the help page correctly? If I do `:doautocmd TextChanged`, then all autocmds triggered by `TextChanged` will run?

Comment: Yes, or you can get specific on which group and/or events to trigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is `:doautocmd`. With this you can trigger all the autocmds in an event, or just those that match a specific pattern. Or you can scope based on autocmd group.  For example, to trigger all the TextChanged events:

```
:doautocmd TextChanged
```